# How do you copy an ImageView to another ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview, clone, deep-copy

Say, ImageView i1 has an image in it and i want to copy ImageView i1 to ImageView i2 not just refer i2 to i1 but actually copy.

```
ImageView i2 = new ImageView(context);
i2 = i1;    //i2 only refers to i1
```

if there is a class and we are passing ImageView as a parameter of its constructor

```
public class CopyEx{
public ImageView i2;

public CopyEx(ImageView i, Context c){
   i2 = new ImageView(c);
   i2 = i;    //This also only refers to i and not copy it
}
}
```

The only thing that seems to work is doing

```
i2.setImageDrawable(i1.getDrawable());
and
i2.setTag(i1.getTag());
```

So is there a way to copy an ImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for copy

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

And use this for pasting

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```